# Finding query using spring data with joining tables

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data

I have such situation. I have two tables with relation One-to-Many. For example Table A with columns `idA, someOtherIdA` and table B with columns `idB, forenKeyIdA, someImportanFieldFromB`. 
Also I'm using spring data and now I need to create method

```
public B findBySomeOtherIdAAndsomeImportanFieldFromB(int someOtherIdA, int someImportanFieldFromB);
```

For this I need to join two table by id

```
Select * From A Join B On A.idA = B.idB Where someOtherIdA = 1 someImportanFieldFromB = 1
```

and I'm using annotation @Query to retrieve result.
But the problem is that I can't automatically map result to object B. 
How could I do that? And is it possible at all to do so without using nativeQuery=true?

Comment: What about `From B join A ...`?

Comment: @StanislavL What do you mean? Just change the order? Or use other language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found is to use JPQL or HQL to get entity and map it. In example I have written it would be like

```
@Query(SELECT b FROM A as a RIGHT JOIN a.forenKeyToAFromB b Where Somevalue=1)
public B findBySomeOtherIdAAndsomeImportanFieldFromB(int someOtherIdA, int someImportanFieldFromB);
```

This method with query will map entity to your existent entity B and solve your tasl